# Changing the variable's value, by using a pointer

Tags: c, pointers, global-variables, local-variables

```
#include <stdio.h>
void functionx(int *ptr) {
    *ptr = *ptr + 100;
}
int main(void) {
    int i = 100;
    int *p = &i;
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    functionx(p);
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

How does the pointer change the value of i variable?
Why is i=200?

Comment: The pointer points to `i`. When you dereference it you actually update what it points to, i.e. `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your variable `i` in memory:

```
+---+
| i |
+---+
```

Then you create a pointer `p` and make it point to `i`:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | i |
+---+     +---+
```

Now you call your function, creating a copy of the pointer `p` and store it in the variable `ptr`. That means you have two pointers both pointing to the same variable `i`:

```
+---------------+
| p (from main) | ---------\
+---------------+          |     +---+
                            >--> | i |
+----------------------+   |     +---+
| ptr (from functionx) | --/
+----------------------+
```

---

If you're wondering about how dereferencing with the `*` operator works, lets get back to the simpler case with only `p` and `i`:

```
+---+     +---+
| p | --> | i |
+---+     +---+
```

By dereferencing the pointer variable `p` we follow the arrow and end up with the variable `i`.

So `*p` and `i` are both the same.

In the `main` function you could to the same as `functionx` by using `p` instead:

```
*p = 300;
printf("i = %d\n", i);  // Will print that i is equal to 300
```